# nginx location directive not working as expected

Tags: http, nginx, reverse-proxy

The following configuration will rewrite `/admin` while proxy_pass `/core`, I can't figure out the reason. Any hint on this? Similar case like this [Nginx: location regex for multiple paths with backend](https://serverfault.com/questions/564127/nginx-location-regex-for-multiple-paths-with-backend) .

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /\#$1 break;
    }
}

location ~ ^/(admin|core)/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1;
}
```

Comment: Is admin a physical directory below the docroot?

Comment: No, there is no admin directory.

Comment: Make sure your request contains the trailing slash. I really don't see another reason why this should break.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `try_files` will simplify things.

```
location /
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ ^/(?:admin|core)/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

Comment: `nginx: [emerg] location "^/(?:core|admin)/" cannot be inside the named location "@backend"`

Comment: Good catch. I've removed the named location from my answer.

Comment: Thanks, you save my day. But why doesn't regular expression capture work?

Comment: The regular expression capture shouldn't be needed with `proxy_pass`. Maybe that was causing a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this variant:

```
location ~ ^/(admin|core)(.*)$ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1;
}
```